# just mark a part of string beetwen two words using Regex

Tags: regex

I have text:

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><img src="/demodomain.com/-13ucJuEQEUw/linktoimg.png"><a href="https://12.imgdomain.com/-13ucJuEQEUw/linktoimg.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="618" data-original-width="1062" height="372" src="https://21.imgdomain.com/-13ucJuEQEUw/WsGsjY2E2bI/-13ucJuEQEUw/linktoimg.jpg" width="640"></a></div>
```

I use `(?<=<img)(.*?)([0-9]+.imgdomain.com)(.*?)(.*?)>` to mark image domain which is in tag `<img>`.
But it doesn't work as my expect, it also marks image domain which in tag `<a>`.

[Demo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJofy.png)

[Demo Regex](https://regex101.com/r/IcjehE/3/)

How can i get correct marking? Thanks!

Comment: Please, use an HTML parser instead. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: :) :). It's not my case if I break lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is too permissive  especially the use of `.*` this matches **any** character instead better use [^>] which will not match `>`  this example matches only the img inside part.

```
(?<=<img)([^>]*)([0-9]+.imgdomain\.com)[^>]*?>
```

While for very some simple cases parsing data from HTML with regex might be ok you really should be aware of the pitfalls. For example a tag with escaped `>` will break the regex above. If it is not an assumption you can make better use a parser. Here the link to [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/IcjehE/4)

Comment: i like `(?<=<img)([^>]*?)([0-9]+.imgdomain.com)[^>]*?>` more. :)

Comment: Happy to help, make sure to accept an answer if it helped you. Have a nice day too!